# Check if the string contains three words in succession

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I am given a string with words and numbers separated by whitespaces (one space). The words contains only letters. I should check if the string contains three words *in succession*. For example, the string `"start 5 one two three 7 end"` contains three words in succession, so it should return `True`.

Example:

```
checkio("Hello World hello") == True
checkio("He is 123 man") == False
checkio("1 2 3 4") == False
checkio("bla bla bla bla") == True
checkio("Hi") == False
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: SO is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service; take the [tour] and review [ask].

Comment: Break this into smaller sub-problems, and then solve those.  You need to: split the string on the whitespace, determine if a string is a word, consider slices of the list with a certain width.  Hint: the first two are already string methods.

Comment: Start with splitting on spaces, then writing a function to return True/False between words or not

Comment: ok there's no code, but at least the requirements are clear. I've voted to reopen. There are much much worse questions out there.

Comment: What's wrong with the question?

Comment: some may think it's missing an attempt. Yes, it's better with an attempt, but I think it's already okay. I'll try to have it reopened

Comment: I got it, next time I'll do, because I just solved it. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one solution using `zip` with `itertools.islice`:

```
from itertools import islice

def checkio(x):
    split = x.split()
    for values in zip(split, islice(split, 1, None), islice(split, 2, None)):
        if all(i.isalpha() for i in values):
            return True
    return False

checkio("Hello World 3 hello 2 hello")  # False
checkio("Hello 3 World hello hello")    # True
```

More efficiently, you can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

def checkio(x):
    for _, j in groupby(x.split(), key=str.isalpha):
        if sum(1 for el in j) == 3:
            return True
    return False

checkio("Hello World 3 hello 2 hello")  # False
checkio("Hello 3 World hello hello")    # True
```

Comment: I see what you've done... Thank you!

Comment: nice, but somehow wasteful because it tests the words multiple times. You may create a boolean array directly: `split = [i.isalpha() for i in x.split()]` then zip that instead.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, Good point. Or use `itertools.groupby` :)

Comment: good. Maybe anonymize your `i` variable as it isn't used. And there's probably a way to avoid creating a list just to count the elements.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, Yeh I always face this thing about trying to avoid creating a `list`, but not sure it's possible without being more verbose, e.g. `sum(1 for e in j)`.

Comment: yeah, that `sum` thing is nice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex for this.

```
import re
bool(re.search(r'\b[a-z]+\s+[a-z]+\s+[a-z]+\b', 'test test 1 test', re.IGNORECASE))
```